# SQL INSERT Command from Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am having a problem with an INSERT statement from Visual Studio actually inserting records into the table

The statement is:

```
Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT Document (CompanyName) VALUES ('Code Test SUCCESS')"

cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1

sqlConnection1.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
sqlConnection1.Close()
```

The problem I think is with:

```
"INSERT Document (CompanyName) VALUES ('Code Test SUCCESS')"
```

In the `Document` table there are only two columns:

- `DocumentID` (Primary Key, auto incrementing)
- `CompanyName`

The application runs fine doesn't throw any errors but the data will not appear as a new record.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: The connection String is

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PostTracker.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

Comment: @kostasch.: the `INTO` is optional - not required

Comment: And do you get an error? If so: **what is** that error?

Comment: Could you add your connection string?

Comment: @marc_s i didn't know. thx for mention

Comment: Dim sqlConnection1 As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PostTracker.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")

Comment: Are you sure that you are check for the new record in the right database?

Comment: Yep, running SELECT * FROM Document to check right after, there is only two test records there at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use DataDirectory substitution string for your connection. So, if you don't have any error then the record is inserted but it is not in the database that you are looking at.

In WinForms applications, the `DataDirectory` is replaced using the working directory of your application. This working directory, inside a debug session of Visual Studio, is `PROJECTFOLDER\BIN\DEBUG` (or x86 variant).

If you check your data using Server Explorer inside Visual Studio chances are that the connection string used by Server Explorer points to the MDF file located in the PROJECTFOLDER where no record has been inserted.

Comment: OK so the problem is with the Connection String then? 
The Database explorer is pointing to the MDF file but its a dropdown from the DataConnections folder?

Comment: No, it is as expected. Just add another connection to your server explorer, point it to the MDF file in the debug folder, and name it something to differentiate from the previuos one. You keep the first for schema changes and other administrative tasks on your db. The second one serves to check if your operations works as expected. Check also the property Copy to Output Directory on the MDF file. It should be set to something Copy if newer.

Comment: Just to clarify, Server Explorer = DataBase Explorer?
I have the connection setup pointing to the Debug now

Comment: VIEW -> Server Explorer, then right click on Data Connections, add Connection (but this is on Vs2013, let me check Vs2010) - Yes the same

Comment: Great so I have the new connection added pointing to the Debug now.
The new connection string (pointing to the debug) does not seem to work from the code though
    Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\v-shgeth\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PostTracker\PostTracker\bin\Debug\PostTracker.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True

Comment: Why you changed it in code? Code could still use the DataDirectory subst. (albeit it should be the same barring path errors)

Comment: OK back to this again :(

The Application will INSERT but only one record and only on the Debug Database and the next time the application is run the record is overwritten.

I am presuming I may need to modify the connection string I just have no idea where to start?

Comment: Check the property Copy to Output Directory on the MDF file listed in your project items. If is set to Copy Always, everytime you start a debug session the file will be copied from the project folder to the bin/debug folder.

Comment: It was set to Copy always on the .MDF